# What is this plant with lobed leaves and pink flowers?

Tags: identification, flowers

I have a plant I am trying to put a name to so I can get relevant information on its care and propagation.

It has deeply lobed leaves, similar to a dandelion and pink petals that fade towards their tips.

[image: unknown flower]

Answer (score 6):

This is a [Gerbera daisy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gerbera) (Gerbera Jamesonii, Gerbera Viridifolia, Gerbera hybrida, and more).

Fertilize them every two weeks with all-purpose water-soluble fertilizer. Water regularly to make sure the soil stays evenly moist while they bloom. After blooming for the season, allow them to dry out slightly. Remove dead blooms with garden shears to encourage the gerberas to keep blooming for as long as possible.

Here are some articles on their culture/propagation:

http://www.gerbera.org/care/gerbera-daisy-plant-care/

http://www.gardeningknowhow.com/ornamental/flowers/gerbera-daisy/growing-gerbera-daisies.htm

http://www.wikihow.com/Grow-Gerbera-Daisies

And one specific to propagation:

http://homeguides.sfgate.com/propagate-gerbera-60030.html

[image]

Comment: Good job Brenn...I have to bop in when I see pots wrapped in foo foo foil and such.  I was a florist.  Bad for drainage!  Good ID!

Comment: And every two weeks for fertilizer might be a bit much depending on formulation!  Always make sure if you want flowers or fruit, N is always a lower percentage than the P and the K...10-10-10 is fine, 4-7-6 is better.  If you use 11-10-10, you will seriously reduce any productive growth and get lots more vegetative.  Hey, I tried using an expensive fert. with a teensy bit more N than P and K. The label said for flowers and vegetables...I knew better but now I really know.  Just a little bit more in percentage relative to P and K makes a HUMONGOUS difference...grins.